# How to convert JS code to be used in ReactJS project

Tags: reactjs, preact

i am trying to build an effect into my product. I came across HTML,CSS and JS file that helps me with this.

But unfortunately, the JS file looks like this. I'm very new to programming, I want to use this for my react project. How should I proceed?

```
var element = document.querySelector("#element"),
    wrapper = document.querySelector("#modal-with-genie-effect"),
    close = document.querySelector("#close"),
    word = document.querySelector("#word"),
    open = document.querySelector("#open-modal-ctr"),
    step0 = "#step-0",
    step2 = "#step-2",
    step3 = "#step-3";

var tl = new TimelineMax();

close.addEventListener("click", function(){

  wrapper.classList.add("active");

  tl
    .to(element, .3, {
      delay: .7,
      y: "-15px",
      scaleY: .9
    })
    .to(element, .3, {
      morphSVG: step2
    })
    .to(element, .3, {
      morphSVG: step3,
    }, "-=.15")
    .to(element, .3, {
      y: "0",
      scaleY: 1,
      onComplete: function(){
        open.classList.add("active");
      }
    }, "-=.15")

});

open.addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.classList.remove("active");

  tl
    .to(element, .3, {
      delay: .45,
      y: "10px",
    })
    .to(element, .3, {
      morphSVG: step2,
    })
    .to(element, .3, {
      morphSVG: step0
    }, "-=.15")
    .to(element, .3, {
      y: "0",
      onComplete: function(){
        wrapper.classList.remove("active");
      }
    }, "-=.3")
});
```

Comment: You should always make sure you completely understand any code you find online before you include it in your project. In this case it seems to be making use of GreenSock's [TimelineMax](https://greensock.com/docs/v2/TimelineMax), I would start by looking through their documentation for how to use the library with React. (Or looking for alternatives)

Comment: Can you include the HTML snippets in your questions? Also, @DBS is right about understanding any code. Without that, it would be hard for you to really understand.